# Merge in a DVCS

Tags: merge, diff, dvcs

For one of my apps I was thinking about implementing branch/merging. I don't understand how to merge without conflicts in some scenarios. Lets take this for example.

Root writes some code. A, B and C pulls from him and adds features. C is done so A and B pull/merge from it. I believe it works by comparing their own against C using root as the base. Now A and B write more features and finish.

Now what happens if I pull from A then pull from B? Their base is root, they both pulled from C so the same lines are edited. How does it know if it is a conflict or not? What if I edit a line C wrote then pull from B? I guess that would be a conflict. Now my last question is What happens if A and B shuffle the location of function after pulling from C? I guess it now comes down to how good the dif recognition is but im unsure how one can pull from both A and B without conflicts

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you *will* get conflicts, if for example A and B edit the same lines (differently). You would then need to manually merge the changes by inspecting them (and maybe talking to A and B!), rather than relying on the DVCS to merge for you.

You might also get logical conflicts (A and B change different sections of the file, so there is no apparent conflict, and the DVCS can handle the merge, but those sections break one anothers' assumptions, so a bug is introduced). Version control can't fix this, only communication between developers, and unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

> How does it know if it is a conflict or not?

- either because the DVCS will tell you: it will trigger a manual resolution of the merge if identical lines are edited
- or because you:

  - know the code well enough to spot *semantic* conflicts
  - have an extended battery of unit test which will flush out semantic conflicts.

But as mentioned in the comments of "[Still not drinking the DVCS Kool-Aid](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.803103.28)", committing and merging regularly (at a much higher pace than with a CVCS, Centralized Version Control system) is key to avoid logic conflicts, or make them as small as possible.
For more on semantic conflicts, see this [Martin Fowler article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/SemanticConflict.html).